# Android Room: naming conventions for DAO interface and abstract class?

Tags: android, android-room

I use Android Room and have a BaseDao which contains basic generic methods like insert, delete etc.

I have an UserDao as interface which extends BaseDao. There are some other abstract method using SQL queries. (getAllUsers, etc)

I want to write some concrete methods for UserDao, but I can't do it in an interface. So I think the better way is to create an abstract class UserDaoImpl to contain those methods.

But how should I name the package and the abstract (but has some concrete methods) class ? I can't call it "UserDaoImpl" because it's afterall an abstract class, not implementations. Or should I rename the interface classes to "UserDaoInterface" ? That would be too boilerplate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whatever it is ,interface or abstract, just YourDataModelName + Dao

Comment: @Stavro Xhardha no in that case I will have 2 classes of the same name

Comment: excuse me the dao is unique , so you either choose the interface or the abstract class . when implementing methods it's room that is doing it for you , you just call them in repository , or viewmodel whatever

Comment: @Stavro Xhardha for some classes I don't need concrete methods, so why change it to abstract class rather than interface ?

Comment: In a DAO you don't have concrete method , you just type the method and the query on the annotation above

Comment: @Stavro Xhardha I need concrete method to insert, update and delete in the case of one-to-many. Imagine every user has one or more devices, I have to write concrete method to persist all devices when persist an user. This is not possible with native Android Room

Comment: And I precise that an User has more one-to-many relations. I can't create all of them none ? (UserWithDevice, UserWithAdresse, UserWithAccomodation)

Comment: check for @Relation annotation here please . This is the official documentation :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation

Comment: @Stavro Xhardha there is no cascade option using Relation

Comment: I'm not sure about it but you have this : `onDelete = CASCADE`